# emit was called after an event handler completed normally

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm getting this error but I can't find what `await` am I missing...
Here's the event method that is triggered in the bloc:

```
Future<void> _performActionOnAuthFacadeWithEmailAndPassword(
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> Function({
required EmailAddress emailAddress,
required Password password,
}) forwardedCall, Emitter<SignInFormState> emit) async {
  emit(state.copyWith(
    isSubmitting: true,
    authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
  ));
  final authFailureOrSuccesOption = await forwardedCall(
      emailAddress: state.emailAddress, password: state.password);
  emit(state.copyWith(
    isSubmitting: false,
    authFailureOrSuccessOption: some(authFailureOrSuccesOption),
  ));
}
```

And here's the method that is passed as an argument to `forwardedCall`:

```
@override
Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  {required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password}) async {
  final emailAddressStr = emailAddress.getOrCrash();
  final passwordStr = password.getOrCrash();

  try {
    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailAddressStr, password: passwordStr);
    return right(unit);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    return left(e.code == 'invalid-email' ||
            e.code == 'user-not-found' ||
            e.code == 'wrong-password'
        ? const AuthFailure.invalidEmailAndPasswordCombination()
        : const AuthFailure.serverError());
  }
}
```

For some reason, the second emit of `_performActionOnAuthFacadeWithEmailAndPassword` throws that error even if the previous line is correctly awaited.

Comment: `_performActionOnAuthFacadeWithEmailAndPassword` seems to be a "private" method of a Cubit, where and how do you call it?

Comment: Also, having a `void` returning method that is `async` is basically always a mistake. Change it to return a Future, even if you decide to not await it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, it's `Future<void>` (edited). `_performActionOnAuthFacadeWithEmailAndPassword` is just a helper function because the register and log in events are mostly the same, so a `forwardedCall` is passed as an argument. Both events are being triggered in the bloc constructor with this syntax: `on<SignInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed>((event, emit) => _signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed(event, emit));`

Comment: Can you post the `_signInWithEmailAndPasswordPressed` method, too please?

Comment: Ok, I needed to await that method too... you pointed me in te right direction. Thanks!